# Why would mocked returnValue not work in tearDown of phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

In the setup of my test class, I create a mock object for a user. When the mock is getting created, it does something like this:

```
$other = $this->getMock( 'Other' );

$user->expects( $this->any() )
     ->method( '_getOtherInstance' )
     ->will( $this->returnValue( $other ) );
```

Now in the deletion of the user, it calls `_getOtherInstance` to remove the tertiary information.

When I run delete in my test class' `tearDown`, before `parent::tearDown`, `_getOtherInstance` returns `null`.

I know the mock is setup correctly since running `delete` in `setUp` works.

What is special about tearDown here? I would imagine that PHPUnit would unset all the mocks and what they return, but not before I call up the chain with `parent::tearDown`.

Comment: You should present the code (or example code) of what you have in `setUp`, the test itself, and `tearDown`. You probably shouldn't do any teardown at all.

Answer (score 1):

Both `setUp` and `tearDown` are empty in `TestCase`, and you don't need to bother calling them from your tests. They are template methods for your use alone. The same applies to the static versions as well.

The method that calls the above and your test method is `runBare`, and it calls `verifyMockObjects` *before* calling `tearDown`. This method calls `__phpunit_verify` on each mock which in turn verifies the expectations and then *deletes* them:

```
public function __phpunit_verify() {
    $this->__phpunit_getInvocationMocker()->verify();
    $this->__phpunit_invocationMocker = NULL;
}
```

Dumping the mock object in `tearDown` shows that the invocation mocker which contains the expectations has been set to `null`, making them unavailable to your `tearDown` method.

> **Danger:** If you really *must* get at the expectation, you can override `verifyMockObjects` in your test case since it's a protected method. Grab what you need and then call the parent method. Just keep in mind that you're treading in the PHPUnit internals which change quite frequently.